# Apache 2.4 rewrite url

Tags: .htaccess, apache2.4

I have this url type (it's an example) (php 7.2):

```
https://www.domaine.net/demo/index.php
https://domaine.net/demo/index.php?Info&Contact
https://domaine.net/demo/index.php?cPath=1
https://domaine.net/demo/index.php?cPath=1_2
https://www.domaine.net/demo/index.php?Products&Description&products_id=1
https://www.domaine.net/demo/index.php?Products&Description&products_id=2
```

It seems apache 2.4 introcuce new element.
How to rewrite correctly this url like this. I have'nt good knowledge with htaccess.
Difficult for me.

```
https://domaine.net/demo/Info&Contact
https://domaine.net/demo/cPath=1
https://domaine.net/demo/cPath=1_2
https://www.domaine.net/demo/Products&Description&products_id=1
https://www.domaine.net/demo/Products&Description&products_id=2
```

What I started :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews

#Tell PHP that the mod_rewrite module is ENABLED.
SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
RewriteEngine On

#WWW => NON-WWW:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/] #not sur
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
????
</IfModule>
```

Tk

Comment: `https://domaine.net/demo/Info&Contact` is not a valid URL. Same later with `https://www.domaine.net/demo/Products&Description&products_id=1` and so on.

Comment: ok,  how to make something correct ?